# Unable to concatenate dataframes correctly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

dfs is:

```
StockCode
84077K     32.694876
23005J     28.248135
85099BJ    24.581063
23084M     24.078340
85099FC    19.276526
Name: 127269, dtype: float64
```

where 127269 is the CustomerID

dfc is:

```
    CustomerID
0       127269
```

I'm trying to concatenate dfs and dfc using this command:

```
final_frame = pd.concat([dfc, dfs], axis=1)
```

I get a result as:

```
         CustomerID      127269
     0     127269.0         NaN
84077K          NaN   32.694876
```

whereas my desired output is:

```
    CustomerID      StockCode
  0     127269         84077K

print (dfs) gives me:

StockCode
84077K    32.694876
Name: 127269, dtype: float64

print(dfc) gives me:
       CustomerID
0      127269
```

Can someone suggest how can this result be achieved?

Comment: The premise seems flawed, you you could align them by first setting the index like this: `dfc.index = dfs.index[:len(dfc)]` concat should then work.

Comment: your approach gives me something like this:                                    
                      CustomerID 127269
StockCode  
84077K             127269 32.694876                                                                      where the StockCode has become the index now which is not what is desired.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `dfs` is a Series and not a dataframe, and you want to concat with the first value of its index. So you should use:

```
final_frame = pd.concat([dfc, dfs.reset_index().iloc[[0], [0]]], axis=1)
```

It should give your expected output.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not: it gives me something like this                                                 
                  CustomerID StockCode                                                                                          
84077K       127269.0           NaN                                                                           
          0               NaN      84077K

Comment: @morelloking: Could you please show in question the output of `print(dfs)` and of `print(dfc)`.

Comment: I added the print (dfs) and print (dfc) outputs in the question

Comment: Let's go step by step. What give `dfs.reset_index()` and `dfs.reset_index().iloc[[0],[0]]`?

Comment: Ok, I've figured out the solution I will post it now

Answer (score 0):

I did the following:

```
dfs = dfs.reset_index()
```

and got the following output:

```
dfs

StockCode   127269
0   84077K  32.694876

dfs1 = dfs['StockCode']

final_frame = pd.concat([dfc, dfs1], axis=1)

final_frame
    CustomerID  StockCode
0       127269  84077K
```